# Using matlab record and save in a specific folder

Tags: matlab, user-interface, save, record, wav

I'm recording a sound and using wavwrite to save the wav file, but I need to save it in a specific folder in C:, such as in c:\monitoringsystem.
That's a part of my code:

```
format shortg
             c = clock;
             fix(c);
             a=num2str(c);
             year=strcat(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5));
             month=strcat(a(19),a(20));
             day=strcat(a(34),a(35));
             hour=strcat(a(48),a(49));
             min=strcat(a(63),a(64));
             sec=strcat(a(74),a(75));
             name=strcat(year,'-',month,'-',day,'-',hour,'-',min,'-',sec);

             wavwrite(y,44100,name);
             y=[];
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I want the program directly save them in a folder. directoryname = uigetdir('c:\monitoringsystem\')
              name = strcat(directoryname, '\', name); this code I must choose the folder but i don't want that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the file path in the name of your sound.

```
         name=strcat(year,'-',month,'-',day,'-',hour,'-',min,'-',sec);

         fullpath = fullfile('C:\MYFOLDER',name);

         wavwrite(y,44100,fullpath);
```

Comment: Error in AI (line 39)
              fullpath = fullfile('C:\monitoringsystem\',name);

Comment: weird,... your variable "name"  is a string ?